# Microsoft Teams Bot - debug refresh token flow

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

While development of a Microsoft Teams Bot I faced a problem that refresh token endpoint is never called. I believe it's my mistake in configurations but I can't find any details what exactly is going wrong. What I did:

1. Set Token Exchange URL in bot settings on Azure side
2. Set scopes to `email offline_access`
3. Checked that `refresh_token` was issued:
   I see that `code` was issues:

```
{
  "code": "[removed for security reasons]",
  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "redirect_uri": "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect",
  "client_id": "microsoft-teams-bot",
  "client_secret": "[removed for security reasons]"
}
```

and after that `refresh_token` was issued by the `code`:

```
{
  "scope": "email offline_access",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "[removed for security reasons]",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "[removed for security reasons]"
}
```

but `refresh_token` is never used after that.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Refreshing token can be handle in backed process.If the current token expires then the refresh auth token method is called. Could you please check this docs for more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens)

Comment: What I'm trying to debug that refresh auth token method is not get called.

Comment: The refresh auth  token will called only when your current token expired. That will be automatically handled in the back end.

Comment: The problem is that it's not called. Access token expires and token exchange endpoint is not called. So users have to relogin every hour. And I can't find why it's not called (

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5990 reposted on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was wrong configuration for the bot. It's using Refresh endpoint to get access token by refresh token (but I though it's using exchange endpoint).